# Unable to find the source of current linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

While trying to install guest additions on a Debian guest I get the error:
Unable to find the source of your current linux Kernel. Specify KERN_DIR= and run Make again.

Some said that this is because linux headers are missing. But when I try to run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-4amd64
```

I get the error could not resolve ftp.debian.org.uk

Comment: Perhaps you need a kernel **sources**, not a **headers** package.

Answer (score 0):

My guest operating system was not connected to my host's wifi. So

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0-4amd64
```

Did not work, but when I edited my VirtualBox network settings to Bridged Adapter, both commands worked. Note that it is also important to run the command

```
sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

to complete the installation of guest editions.